# VBA to copy certain columns to all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm looking to create code for copying certain columns (AH to AX) across all worksheets then skipping worksheets named "Aggregated" & "Collated Results"

I have this already

```
Sub FillSheets()
 Dim ws As Worksheets
 Dim worksheetsToSkip As Variant
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim sh As Sheet1


 Set rng = sh.Range("AH1:AX7200")


 worksheetsToSkip = Array("Aggregated", "Collated Results")
  For Each ws In Worksheets
  If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, worksheetsToSkip, 0)) Then




End Sub
```

Comment: Is the final `s` in `Dim ws as Worksheets` a typo? Because it should be `As Worksheet`.

Comment: `Set rng = sh.Range("AH1:AX7200")` will set it to `AH1:AX7200` on the `sh` sheet and it will not change as you loop through worksheets. Is this your intent? (It would be helpful to know what your question is)

Comment: @BigBen - correct, edited my comment accordingly. Thanks for the catch

Comment: OP, can you explain what range you want to copy on each sheet and where you want the ranges to be pasted. It also looks like you are always grabbing the same range - do you actually want to do this? Or do you want to grab a dynamic range (from first row down to last used row)?

Comment: I have a template with equations in columns AH to AX, it will always go from AH1 to AX7200. I know I could just highlight the columns and the worksheets I want to copy into then use the fill across worksheets. But I want to add this into my automation.

@BigBen yes the s is a typo

Comment: @urdearboy Yes it is the same range from the same worksheet but copied across all worksheets

Answer (score 0):

This will

1. Loop through sheets
2. "Copy" data from `AH1 - AX1` down to the last used row that is determined by `Column AH` (Update column if needed)
3. "Paste" data on a sheet named `Sheet1` (Update if needed). The data will be pasted in `Column AH` on the first available blank row. It's not clear what column you want to paste the data in. You just need to change `AH` to `Some Column` to modify

"Copy" and "Paste" are in quotes because we are really just transferring values here since this is quicker. We are actually setting the values of two equal sized ranges equal to each other.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub AH_AX()

'Update "Sheet1" to sheet where data is being pasted
Dim ms As Worksheet: Set ms = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsLR As Long, msLR As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range, PasteRange As Range

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Aggregated" And ws.Name <> "Collated Results" Then

        'Determine last rows
        wsLR = ws.Range("AH" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        msLR = ms.Range("AH" & ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

        'Set Ranges
        Set CopyRange = ws.Range("AH1:AX" & LR)
        Set PasteRange = ms.Range("AH" & msLR).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count)

        'Value Transfer (Quicker than copy/paste)
        PasteRange.Value = CopyRange.Value

    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Would I have to enter the name of the sheet I want to paste into each time, as each time I use this there could be 100 sheets or there could be 5 and the names will change each time I use it only "aggregated" "Collated Results" "Template" will stay the same